# Using a custom collection extending from a dict() with SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, inheritance, collections, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use a custom collection to "connect" (or relate) two classes but I haven't been able to do it. Maybe I got the whole concept of the [SqlAlchemy custom collections](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/collections.html#custom-collection-implementations) wrong, but let me explain what I am doing (and see if someone can give me a hint, or something)

I have a Parent class (which some of you will remember from other questions) with a couple of connectors fields (kind of lists) in it. One of the connectors will store instances of a Child() class whose type is "*VR*" and the other will store children with a "*CC*" type.

I don't really need persistence for the collection used to store the children, but I need it to be of an special class so it will have some methods that I have implemented and that need to be there. That would be the "*ZepConnector*" class (and, for purposes of the example, it's method foo() is the one I need to use). As you can see in the following lines, I randomly test its availability in the addChild1() method of the Parent.

--------------------- Parent.py -----------------

```
from megrok import rdb
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import and_
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer
from sqlalchemy.types import String
from mylibraries.database.tests.Child import Child
from mylibraries.database.tests.Tables import testMetadata
from mylibraries.database.tests.ZepConnector import ZepConnector

class Parent(rdb.Model):
    rdb.metadata(testMetadata)
    rdb.tablename("parents_table")
    rdb.tableargs(schema='test2', useexisting=False)

    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    _whateverField1 = Column("whatever_field1", String(16)) #Irrelevant
    _whateverField2 = Column("whatever_field2", String(16)) #Irrelevant

    child1 = relationship(
        "Child",
        uselist=True,
        primaryjoin=lambda: and_((Parent.id == Child.parent_id), (Child.type == "VR")),
        collection_class=ZepConnector("VR")
        )

    child2 = relationship(
        "Child",
        uselist=True,
        primaryjoin=lambda: and_((Parent.id == Child.parent_id), (Child.type == "CC")),
        collection_class=ZepConnector("CC")
        )

    def __init__(self):
        print "Parent __init__"
        self._whateverField1 = "Whatever1"
        self._whateverField2 = "Whatever2"
        self.child1 = ZepConnector("VR")
        self.child2 = ZepConnector("CC")

    def addChild1(self, child):
        if isinstance(child, Child):
            print("::addChild1 > Testing .foo method: " + str(self.child1.foo()))
            # The line above doesn't really makes much 
            # but testing the accessibility of the .foo() method.
            # As I'll explain later, it doesn't work
            self.child1.append(child)

    def addChild2(self, child):
        if isinstance(child, Child):
            self.child2.append(child)
```

---

Please note that I'm using megrok. For those who are not familiar with it, allow me to explain that it is just a tool that maps the Python class to an SqlAlchemy mapper itself and makes it a little bit more "*programmer friendly*" when using the [Grok framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok_%28web_framework%29).

I guess The mapping of the Parent() class in regular SqlAlchemy would resemble something like:

```
mapper(Parent, parents_table, properties={
    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    _whateverField1 = Column("whatever_field1", String(16)) #Irrelevant
    _whateverField2 = Column("whatever_field2", String(16)) #Irrelevant
    child1 = relationship( # etc, etc, etc
})
#
```

but I'm 100%... erm... 90%... erm... 70% certain that using that tool is not what lead me to ask what I'm going to ask here (I mean: I don't think is interfering with the SqlAlchemy Custom Collections thing)

A child is a very simple class:

--------------- Child.py --------------------------

```
import random

from megrok import rdb
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer
from sqlalchemy.types import String
from mylibraries.database.tests.Tables import testMetadata

class Child(rdb.Model):
    rdb.metadata(testMetadata)
    rdb.tablename("children_table")
    rdb.tableargs(schema='test2', useexisting=False)

    parent_id = Column("parent_id", Integer, ForeignKey("test2.parents_table.id"), primary_key=True)
    type = Column("type", String(2), nullable=True, primary_key=True)
    hasher = Column("hasher", String(5))

    def __init__(self):
        self.type = None
        self.hasher = self.generateHasher()

    def setType(self, typeParameter):
        if typeParameter in set(["VR", "CC"]):
            self.type = typeParameter

    @staticmethod
    def generateHasher():
        retval = str()
        for i in random.sample('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 5):
            retval += i
        return retval
```

---

Let's say every Child instance will have a unique "hasher" field that can be used as a key in a dictionary (the example above is far away from the reality, but it illustrates a little bit how the Child will work and for being able to create a test)

And now my custom connector. I want it to behave as a *list* or a *set* (more like a *set*, although I don't mind much) but it's a class that inherits from dict.

-------------------- ZepConnector.py --------------------

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import collection

class ZepConnector(dict):
    __emulates__ = list

    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type 
        # The 'type' will be "VR" or "CC" and it will be stamped
        # on every Child() class added through this ZepConnector

    def foo(self):
        return True

    @collection.appender
    def append(self, item):
        #Appends a child to itself
        if self.foo():
            item.setType(self.type)
            self[item.hasher] = item

    @collection.remover
    def remove(self, item):
        try:
            del self[item.hasher]
        except ValueError, e:
            print("::remove > Got exception when trying to remove entry=" + str(item.hasher) + ". The exception is: " + str(e))

    def extend(self, items):
        pass
```

---

But I don't know why, the "ZepConnector" instances in the Parent class don't seem to be of a "*ZepConnector*" type but of an "*InstrumentedList*":

When in the addChild1 method of Parent() I try to test the .foo() method (which should just print "True") I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Showing whole traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ae/mytests-cms/grokserver/eggs/zope.publisher-3.12.0-py2.4.egg/zope/publisher/publish.py", line 134, in publish
    result = publication.callObject(request, obj)
  File "/home/ae/mytests-cms/grokserver/eggs/grok-1.1rc1-py2.4.egg/grok/publication.py", line 89, in callObject
    return super(ZopePublicationSansProxy, self).callObject(request, ob)
  File "/home/ae/mytests-cms/grokserver/eggs/zope.app.publication-3.10.2-py2.4.egg/zope/app/publication/zopepublication.py", line 205, in callObject
    return mapply(ob, request.getPositionalArguments(), request)
  File "/home/ae/mytests-cms/grokserver/eggs/zope.publisher-3.12.0-py2.4.egg/zope/publisher/publish.py", line 109, in mapply
    return debug_call(obj, args)
  File "/home/ae/mytests-cms/grokserver/eggs/zope.publisher-3.12.0-py2.4.egg/zope/publisher/publish.py", line 115, in debug_call
    return obj(*args)
  File "/home/ae/mytests-cms/grokserver/eggs/grokcore.view-1.13.2-py2.4.egg/grokcore/view/components.py", line 101, in __call__
    return mapply(self.render, (), self.request)
  File "/home/ae/mytests-cms/grokserver/eggs/zope.publisher-3.12.0-py2.4.egg/zope/publisher/publish.py", line 109, in mapply
    return debug_call(obj, args)
  File "/home/ae/mytests-cms/grokserver/eggs/zope.publisher-3.12.0-py2.4.egg/zope/publisher/publish.py", line 115, in debug_call
    return obj(*args)
  File "/home/ae/mytests-cms/grokserver/src/grokserver/app.py", line 1575, in render
    mylibraries.database.tests.Test.runWholeTest()
  File "/home/ae/mytests-cms/mylibraries/database/tests/Test.py", line 54, in runWholeTest
    __test()
  File "/home/ae/mytests-cms/mylibraries/database/tests/Test.py", line 35, in __test
    parent.addChild1(child)
  File "/home/ae/mytests-cms/mylibraries/database/tests/Parent.py", line 54, in addChild1
    print("::addChild1 > Testing .foo method: " + str(self.child1.foo()))
AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'foo'
Debug at: http://127.0.0.1:8080/_debug/view/1289342582
```

It's strange... The **init** method of the ZepConnector is properly executed... but when I try to use it, it doesn't seem to be ZepConnector...

I did a couple of more tests, but all unsuccessful:

In a second try I wrote:

```
class ZepConnector(dict):
    __emulates__ = set
```

but this even makes things worse, because I get:

```
TypeError: Incompatible collection type: ZepConnector is not list-like
```

In a third (or second point two) try, I though... "well... if it's saying that ZepConnector is not a list, maybe telling the Parent() not to use a list in the relationship may help... Maybe stating that the collection_class is a ZepConnector makes ynnecessary the uselist parameter in the relationship..."

And so I wrote:

```
child1 = relationship(
    "Child",
    uselist = False,
    primaryjoin=lambda: and_((Parent.id == Child.parent_id),(Child.type == "VR")),
    collection_class=ZepConnector("VR")
    )
```

But that threw a creepy exception talking about a field which I shouldn't see and that I don't want to see... ever... **:-D**

```
AttributeError: 'ZepConnector' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

I am using Python2.4 and SqlAlchemy 0.6.6, just in case it's relevant.

If someone has any ideas, guidance, counseling... whatever... I'd really appreciate you sharing it with me... erm... us...

Thank you in advance!

(if you have reached this line, you certainly deserve a "thank you" just for your patience reading this huge post)

Comment: I don't even start to comprehend your code. Please cut it down, separate your problems (I'm sure, there are more than one), and make a minimal demonstration of each separate.

Comment: @knitti > Well... I don't think I can split this question in other questions. The main problem can be read as: *"How can I use my ZepConnector class as the collection_class between the Parent() and Child() classes?"* Thank you for reading it, though

Comment: I'm not convinced, but not entirely thrown off :-) Could you be persuaded to include the full traceback of the AttributeError? I'm especially interested in the line before control flow dives into `sqlalchemy.util`

Comment: @knitti > Jeez... It's certainly a huge posts! Thank you for reading it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

I had also asked the same question in the SqlAlchemy google group and I just got an answer.

http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/msg/5c8fc09a75fd4fa7

Quote:

> So this is incorrect -
>   collection_class takes a class or
>   other callable as an argument that
>   will produce an instance of your
>   collection.  The ZepConnector source
>   you have below indicates that
>   ZepConnector("VR") is an instance of
>   the collection.   You need to use a
>   lambda: there.   The other errors
>   you're getting would appear to extend
>   from that (and is also why **init** is
>   called on ZepConnector - you're
>   calling it yourself).

Thanks to Michael Bayer (and to all the people that tried to help, even by reading such a humongous post)

Comment: OK, cool then. Out of interest: what problem do you try to solve?

Comment: @knitti > I wasn't able to use my own class ZepConnector as a *collection_class*. I didn't know if it was possible to use a class extending from a dict (mapped object) to emulate the behavior of a set/list, because in the SqlAlchemy examples I had seen they use a collection_class classes that extend from lists as lists or classes that extend from dict as dicts, but I wanted something extending from a dict behave as a list... I didn't even know if that was doable (I thought it was but I wasn't sure)

Comment: It turns out that the only thing I had to do was, in Parent.py writing: collection_class=lambda:ZepConnector("VR")  instead of collection_class= ZepConnector("VR")