# python SQLAlchemy many to many unique constraint only working one way

Tags: python, database, flask, orm, sqlalchemy

I am using python 2.7 with sqlAlchemy over sqllite, in a flask app, and trying to map a relationship between two models, the models are Lad and Crew, a Lad can have many crews and vice verse, the only limitation is that the pair should be unique, e.g A lad can only be in a crew once and vice verse, I've built the models, and when trying to add a crew to the same lad twice, the primary key constraint is limiting me, but when trying to add the same lad to a crew twice, it let's me, which should also be forbidden.

```
peopleInCrews = Table("peopleInCrewsAssosiation", Base.metadata,
                      Column("A", Integer, ForeignKey("lads.id", ondelete="CASCADE", onupdate="CASCADE"), primary_key=True),
                      Column("B", Integer, ForeignKey("crews.id", ondelete="CASCADE", onupdate="CASCADE"), primary_key=True),
                      PrimaryKeyConstraint("A", "B"))


class Lad(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'lads'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    firstName = Column(String(50), unique=False)
    lastName = Column(String(50), unique=False)

    crews = relationship("Crew", secondary=peopleInCrews, back_populates="lads")



class Crew(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'crews'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    name = Column(String(20), unique=False)

    lads = relationship("Lad", secondary = peopleInCrews, back_populates = "crews")#, cascade = "all, delete")
```

When I start with create a lad and a crew as follows:

```
c = Crew("name") 
l = Lad("first", "last")
```

The following code throws a duplicate error as it should:

```
c.lads.append(lad)
c.lads.append(lad)
```

The following code is expected to do the same but just adds the lad twice to the crew.lads:

```
l.crews.append(c)
l.crews.append(c)
```

What am i missing here?

Edit: 
Some has suggested this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335507/why-dont-duplicates-in-a-relationship-violate-a-uniqueconstraint) one, What's different here, is that I am using primaryKeyConstraint, and that it's working in one direction and not working in the other direction. e.g. you can add the same crew twice to a Lad.crews, but you can't add the same lad to a Crew.lads. it's supposed to be a symmetric unique constraint and work the same both ways.

Comment: Here  `l =Lad("first","last")` will create a new object with new id. So technically it is treating it as a new object and hence allowing it. Values might be same but objects are different. Does it make sense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't duplicates in a relationship violate a UniqueConstraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335507/why-dont-duplicates-in-a-relationship-violate-a-uniqueconstraint)

Comment: @mad_ I am adding the same object twice and creating it once, I don't think this is the issue here

Comment: @univerio I am not using a unique contraint but primarykeyconstraint, this is not a dup

Comment: @thebeancounter `PRIMARY KEY`s are pretty much equivalent to `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`s. The takeaway from that question is that you are expected to not add the same object to the same relationship unless you're using `collection_class=set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using

```
db_session.add(c)
db_session.add(l)
c.lads.append(lad)
c.lads.append(lad)
l.crews.append(c)
l.crews.append(c)
db_session.refresh(lad)
db_session.refresh(c)
```

It did not provide an exception, but it solved the duplication inside the objects.